# Deep learning model predicts mostly around the mean of the actuals?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I have a 1DCNN model that seems to only predict close to the mean of the actual values in my test dataset. Is this a poor model based on the fact the distribution of the actuals vs predictions are radically different?

[Actual vs Predicted density plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAxhq.png)

My questions are:

1. What could this graph indicate about my predictions? Is it normal for a model to simply predict the mean? Is that what will happen if it can't learn much about the dataset?
2. Doesn't it seem that MAE is not a good metric? Is it misleading and should I use a different one?

I am trying to improve the model by decreasing MAE, but as it decreases, it simply moves toward the mean value of the actual data and further from the spread of the real distribution. You can see the SD of my predictions is around 9 and the SD of the actual data is about 22. The users want the results in the actual units, which is why I am supplying MAE. Plus I have other baselines to compare to with MAE. I feel it is a very misleading metric.

I have about 30 weather and soil features, all continuous and scaled. 6 years of daily weather data at several thousand weather locations. At each location I have a single target value per year. The 1DCNN architecture is shown below. I split my data with the first 5 years in training and the last year is test.  The data spans 3 US states and there are about 9 physical districts per state.  I tried building a model per state (just 3 models) but my performance is poor for each. If I build it down to the district level, I can get acceptable results. I don't expect great results, but I'm really just trying to figure out why it's circling the mean.

My model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=13, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=13, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
opt = Adam(lr=.0001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt)
```

I'm training the model on different size datasets to capture results throughout the year as more weather data is added, how ever the predictions are similar for each model.

[multiple models showing same situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCmRK.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

In the question, you said you are using MAE(Mean Absolute Error), but in code, you have used the loss as `mean_squared_error`.
Any reason for that?
Some debugging ideas.

1. Check the distribution of your training and validation split dependent.
2. Bucket the values into classes and try to build a classifier, and see if you still face the same issue, this could help you pinpoint which part of the distribution is not being captured properly.
3. If you are using a structured dataset, try Tree-based algorithms for example XGBoost or Random Forest, for something to see if the algorithm might be the problem.

Comment: No real reason, the results are the same.

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of is that your training data does not sufficiently represent the distribution you are trying to capture. I have added a few debugging techniques you can try out.